# Create order before payment process

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am using payment gateway plugin. The issue is once I click on create order ( place order ) button. The order will create and the confirmation email and SMS will send.

What I know is this is the Magento default behavior but not acceptable for customers if the payment failed.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which payment method did you try?

Comment: @SohelRana  I'm using a local payment gateway called Urway. it seems they using one97
https://www.one97.com/payments.php